# Trying to add users to office 365 group (AzureAD)

Tags: powershell, azure, office365, azure-powershell

I have a problem adding users to my office 365 security group.

The code I'm trying to use is:

```
$groupid = Get-AzureADGroup | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like "Grp*"}
$useradd = Get-AzureADUser | select userprincipalname,objectid | where {$_.UserPrincipalName -like ‘*PS@*’}
$useradd | foreach {Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $groupid.ObjectId -RefObjectId $useradd.ObjectId}
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
Add-AzureADGroupMember : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'ObjectId'.
```

Comment: um... what line? The third line? You're passing in an object when you need to pass in a string. What I would do now is google the cmdlet and find out what types the parameters are.... but why don't you try it first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use this script:

```
$groupid = Get-AzureADGroup | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like "Grp*"}
$useradd = Get-AzureADUser | select userprincipalname,objectid | where {$_.UserPrincipalName -like ‘*PS@*’}
$users = $useradd.objectId
foreach($user in $users){Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $groupid.ObjectId -RefObjectId $user}
```

Here is the result:
[image]

---

Update:

Please test this script to find the root cause:

```
$groupid = Get-AzureADGroup | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like "group2"}
$useradd = Get-AzureADUser | select userprincipalname,objectid | where {$_.UserPrincipalName -like ‘w*’}
$users = $useradd.objectid
foreach($user in $users){
$user
Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $groupid.ObjectId -RefObjectId $user
}
```

[image]

---

**Update:**

We can use this script to add multiple users to multiple groups:

```
$groupid = Get-AzureADGroup | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like "sg*"}
$useradd = Get-AzureADUser | select userprincipalname,objectid | where {$_.UserPrincipalName -like ‘ja*’}
$users = $useradd.objectId
$groupids = $groupid.ObjectId
foreach($user in $users){
foreach($groupid in $groupids){
Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $groupid -RefObjectId $user}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i still get the same error.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFhjF.png

Best regards,
Andreas Andersson

Comment: @AndreasAndreasson could you please print $users?

Comment: @AndreasAndreasson are there something in `$users` ?

Comment: Yes there is:
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $users
a3d2b6f0-a5f9-4abf-96d2-6ec0247e4a0d
8188fb89-0fcb-45d5-8643-e9d887657da4

Comment: There are two users in it? please try this, `$groupid = Get-AzureADGroup | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like "group2"}
$useradd = Get-AzureADUser | select userprincipalname,objectid | where {$_.UserPrincipalName -like ‘q*’}
$users = $useradd.objectid
foreach($user in $users){
$user
Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $groupid.ObjectId -RefObjectId $user
}` and put the result here.

Comment: @AndreasAndreasson could you please show me the output, also you can show me the screenshot, thanks:)

Comment: Sorry was busy with an event. The results are:
$groupid = Get-AzureADGroup | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like "Grp1"}
$useradd = Get-AzureADUser | select userprincipalname,objectid | where {$_.UserPrincipalName -like ‘*PS@*’}
$users = $useradd.objectid
foreach($user in $users){
$user
Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $groupid.ObjectId -RefObjectId $user
}
a3d2b6f0-a5f9-4abf-96d2-6ec0247e4a0d
8188fb89-0fcb-45d5-8643-e9d887657da4
And it works and adds the two users to the group Grp1 but when i try to add them too Grp1 & Grp2 i get the error i had before about system.object.

Comment: Yes you have been very helpful, if you could check the possibillity to add multiple users to two or more groups also it would be helpful. Thank you! :)

Comment: @AndreasAndreasson I have update my answer, please check it, we can use PowerShell add multiple users to multiple groups.

Comment: Thanks! @JasonYe
Works perfectly